# Split string into 2 strings based on a delimiter

Tags: java, string

Does anybody know if there is a solid library based method to achieve the following.

Say I have the string

```
"name1, name2, name3, name4"
```

and I want to parse it into 2 strings based on the comma delimiter.

I would like the strings to look like this:

```
string1 = "name1";
string2 = "name2, name3, name4";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(", *");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    string1 = inputString.substring(0, matcher.start());
    string2 = inputString.substring(matcher.end());
}
```

Comment: Just in case the space would be missing or there would be more than one.

Answer (score 39):

you could use [`yourString.split(", ", 2)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

```
String str = "name1, name2, name3, name4";

String[] parts = str.split(", ", 2);
String string1 = parts[0];
String string2 = parts[1];

System.out.println(string1);  // prints name1
System.out.println(string2);  // prints name2, name3, name4
```

You could also use `yourString.indexOf(", ")` and `yourString.substring(...)`.

Comment: +1: You will get only one string if there is no seperator. ;)

Comment: Yep... the op leaves that case as UB though :-)

Comment: With this approach am I correct in thinking that I will lose the commas in the string? I'd like them to remain in the second string

Comment: uhm, you'll keep them. Didn't you see what the second println prints?

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "hello=goodmorning,2,1"
String[] str = s.split("=");  //now str[0] is "hello" and str[1] is "goodmorning,2,1"
String str1 = str[0];  //hello
String[] str2 = str[1].split(",");  //now str2[0] is "goodmorning" and str2[1] is "2,1"
```