# How to split by every space preceded by a dot or colon?

Tags: java, regex

I've got a string in Java: `Acidum acetylsalic. Acid.ascorb, Calcium` which I want to split. The string has to be cut after every space preceded by a dot or colon: `,[space]` or `.[space]`

In result I need three strings: `Acidum acetylsalic`, `Acid.ascorb`, `Calcium`

I know I need some regex and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13223262/1873995) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993823/1873995) I tried `"\, |\. "` but I doubt that's not how regex work.

Comment: replace all dot or commas with commas or dots then split your string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Splitting a string into 2 strings based on a delimiter.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631808/java-splitting-a-string-into-2-strings-based-on-a-delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

Split by

```
"[,.] "
```

`[,.]` - character set with one *comma* or *dot*

---

The problem with your original regex is that you need to escape the *dot* once to make it a *literal dot* and a second time to escape the *slash* escaping it. It will also work if you change it to:

```
", |\\. "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.split("[\\.,]\\s")
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Use split("(\.\s)|(\,\s)")

You need to encode special characters see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Hi LS include relevant data from the link to your answer because links have the tendency to change over due course of time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String str="Acidum acetylsalic. Acid.ascorb, Calcium";

    String[] resStr= str.split("[.,][\\s]");

    for (String res : resStr) {

        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Output :

```
Acidum acetylsalic
Acid.ascorb
Calcium
```